# rename command usage in ubuntu machine for rename a set of files

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting, ubuntu-14.04

I have a shell script for renaming multiple files in a folder. It works on a rhel host but throws error on a ubuntu14 host.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SOME_NUMBER=1
rename _file_name.c _file_${SOME_NUMBER}.c path/of/file/*_file_name.c
```

What changes shall i make in the code to make it work on a ubuntu14 host?

EDIT-1:

For running the code on ubuntu machine i made following change and it works:

```
rename 's/\_file_name.c$/\_file_1.c/' path/of/file/*_file_name.c
```

but following doesn't works and i get below error message:

```
rename 's/\_file_name.c$/\_file_${SOME_NUMBER}.c/' path/of/file/*_file_name.c
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Global symbol "$SOME_NUMBER" requires explicit package name at (eval 1) line 1.
Global symbol "$SOME_NUMBER" requires explicit package name at (eval 1) line 1.
```

Comment: That's a `perl` error message, not `bash`. But `${SOME_NUMBER}` will be exxpanded by the shell, it should never be seen by `perl`.

Comment: Is that an exact copy of the script? You'd get that error if `_file_${SOME_NUMBER}.c` was in single quotes.

Comment: you are correct Barmar. I have edited the problem statement.

Comment: Do you know @ShijithR? They posted a very similar question 1 hour ago (they've since deleted it), and also posted the wrong types of quotes in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes prevent parameter expansion. Because Perl and shell syntax is similar in this regard, the literal string `s/\_file_name.c$/\_file_${SOME_NUMBER}.c/` is passed to Perl, where it tries to expand the undefined variable `$SOME_NUMBER`.

Use double quotes instead:

```
rename "s/\_file_name.c$/\_file_${SOME_NUMBER}.c/" path/of/file/*_file_name.c
```

See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Be sure that the value of `SOME_NUMBER` in your shell script really is just a number, or at least something that, when expanded, produces a valid Perl expression.

Comment: Thanks Barmar and Chepner. The suggested solution has worked for me.